# Command line gives different hash key for signKey.jks

Tags: android, facebook, hash

According to facebook sdk I used

```
    keytool -exportcert -alias YOUR_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS -keystore YOUR_RELEASE_KEY_PATH | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

to get the hash key. But I got error while login that hash key did not matched. I am using the same apk signed same signing key. Then I used

```
         PackageInfo info;
try {
    info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.you.name", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
    for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
        MessageDigest md;
        md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
        md.update(signature.toByteArray());
        String something = new String(Base64.encode(md.digest(), 0));
        //String something = new String(Base64.encodeBytes(md.digest()));
        Log.e("hash key", something);
    }
} catch (NameNotFoundException e1) {
    Log.e("name not found", e1.toString());
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
    Log.e("no such an algorithm", e.toString());
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("exception", e.toString());
}
```

It is giving me the actual hash key. My Question is why hash key generated from command line is different than from code when I am using the same .jks(key) file.